# Why do i need to double tap screen to make my website looks okay?

Tags: mobile, zooming, responsive-design

I am currently building a responsive mobile webpage.
My question is - when i enter the webpage on the phone i have to double tap it to look good - else its all way to zoomed in. Is there any way to prevent this?

webpage link

http://makeitweb.se/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

I think your meta viewport tag should look more like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```